# Attach Visual Studio 2013 (or 2015) JS debugger to browser using IIS (not Express)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio, iis, visual-studio-2015

Attaching Visual Studio debugger to IIS to debug C# code in an ASP.NET application is simple.

However I would like to debug the JavaScript in Visual Studio too. If I run the website under IIS Express with Internet Explorer, the browser link is set up automatically and I can put breakpoints in the JS code inside Visual Studio, and debug it just like server side code.

I couldn't make it work if I run the website it under IIS. The browser link seemed to be there: when I selected "reload linked browsers" it reloaded the page in IE. I set breakpoints, but instead of the "solid red disc" breakpoints they had a smaller white dot inside, and they didn't get hit.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a tutorial for it? All tutorials I could find were related to attaching the debugger to debug server side code, but not the browser link part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z959x58c.aspx) might be what you are looking for. It details the steps to attach a running IE instance to VS.